# Ruby parse <a> link info from Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, mechanize

I pulled a `Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet` from a page and here's the result:

```
<a href="http://www.goldsteinpatentlaw.com" target="_blank" title="Goldstein Patent Law ( U.S.A. )">
    <img src="http://www.asdf.com/LBM_Images/Offices//law-firm-goldstein-patent-law-photo-1258381.jpg" height="62" width="100" alt="Goldstein Patent Law (U.S.A.)">
</a>
```

I can't figure out how to turn that (obvious to humans) `<a>` tag into a Mechanize/Nokogiri-parsed object so I can easily retrieve bits of info from the link.

The Nokogiri/Mechanize docs are really confusing because I never know which to look at. Not sure which came first, which uses which, etc. Seems very overcomplicated for the simple scraping & parsing I'm trying to do.

Comment: Nokogiri is just an XML/HTML parser. Mechanize is an HTTP user agent for interacting with web servers. What's your problem here? Are you trying to parse that text? If it's a NodeSet, it's already parsed.

Comment: "The Nokogiri/Mechanize docs are really confusing because I never know which to look at." Mechanize is a totally different tool from Nokogiri, that happens to use Nokogiri internally, so don't look at Mechanize for any Nokogiri information. Nokogiri is a parser, so look at the [Nokogiri::XML::Node](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html) and [...NodeSet](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html) documentation for the majority of what you need to know. From there you can nose around and learn what else it can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IS this what you are looking for?

```
require 'nokogiri'
str = '<a href="http://www.goldsteinpatentlaw.com" target="_blank" title="Goldstein Patent Law ( U.S.A. )">
          <img src="http://www.asdf.com/LBM_Images/Offices//law-firm-goldstein-patent-law-photo-1258381.jpg" height="62" width="100" alt="Goldstein Patent Law (U.S.A.)">
       </a>'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(str)
link = doc.at('a')
#=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x1744488 name="a" attributes=[
     #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x174444c name="href" value="http://www.goldsteinpatentlaw.com">, 
     #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x1744440 name="target" value="_blank">,
     #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x1744434 name="title" value="Goldstein Patent Law ( U.S.A. )">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x1743d20 "\n    ">, 
     #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x1743c9c name="img" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x1743c60 name="src" value="http://www.asdf.com/LBM_Images/Offices//law-firm-goldstein-patent-law-photo-1258381.jpg">, 
     #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x1743c54 name="height" value="62">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x1743c48 name="width" value="100">, 
     #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x1743c3c name="alt" value="Goldstein Patent Law (U.S.A.)">]>,
     #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x17433d8 "\n">]>
```

You can use `at`,  `at_css` or `at_xpath` selectors to get just what you want then do things like

```
link.attributes["href"].value
#=> "http://www.goldsteinpatentlaw.com"
link.attributes["title"].value
#=> "Goldstein Patent Law ( U.S.A. )"
```

Comment: That IS what I was looking for. I've done something similar to that in the past and forgot how to do it. Thanks again!

Comment: "You can use css or xpath selectors to get just what you want"... well, kinda. `css` and `xpath`, like `search`, return a NodeSet, which is like an Array. `at`, `at_xpath` and `at_css` return a Node. How you work with them can seem similar, a lot of similar methods in NodeSet and Node will result in very different output.

Comment: @theTinMan you are correct I was oversimplifying for the sake of the OP but i have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: **at, at_xpath and at_css return a Node.** Well, kinda.  They return a Node in the same sense that the constructor, `{}`, returns a BasicObject.

Answer (score 2):

A NodeSet is like an array. If you use puts() on a NodeSet, then, just like when you use puts on an Array, ruby will output a string representation of each item in the NodeSet on a separate line.  NodeSets can contain various objects, but typically they will contain objects called `<Nokogiri::XML::Element>`, which represent the tags in your html.

It is apparent from your output that your Nodeset has only one item, and what you are seeing is the string representation of that item.  Here is an example:

```
require 'nokogiri'

str = "<div>hello</div><div>world</div>"
html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(str)

divs = html_doc.xpath("//div")

divs.each do |div|
  p div
end

puts '*' * 10
puts divs


    --output:--
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x80836ec4 name="div" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80836a00 "hello">]>
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x80836668 name="div" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80836064 "world">]>
**********
<div>hello</div>
<div>world</div>
```

So you just have to retrieve the first element of your NodeSet, just like you would retrieve the first element in an Array:

```
p divs[0]
```

Or, if you know there is only going to be one element in your NodeSet, then you can use:

```
div = html_doc.at_xpath("//div")
```

which instead of returning a NodeSet just returns the first Element matching the xpath.

When you really want to know what you've got, you should use `p` instead of `puts`.

Comment: "if you know there is only going to be one element in your NodeSet" should also say ", or you want only the first matching element,".

Comment: @the Tin Man, My answer already contains that information: **which instead of returning a NodeSet just returns the first Element matching the xpath.**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little late here, but for more on NodeSets specifically, look here: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet#attr-instance_method

According to their docs, this is the code I used to do what you were trying to do and it works!

```
result.search("h2 > a").attr("href")
```